# Access usermanager in TypeFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm creating a custom Authorize Attribute in ASP.NET Core. To do that I need to get my userroles, which I can find in the UserManager. How can I access it? I can get it in my controller, but not in the filter I think.

My code looks like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles) : base(typeof(CustomAuthorizeFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { roles };
    }
}

public class CustomAuthorizeFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private string[] _roles;

    public CustomAuthorizeFilter(IReadOnlyList<object> arguments)
    {
        _roles = (string[])arguments;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var username = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.First().Value;
        //var roles = usermanager.

        var hasClaim = true; 
        if (!hasClaim)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();

        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filter decorated by `TypeFilterAttribute` can use built-in DI to resolve dependencies. For example `ILoggerFactory` :

```
public CustomAuthorizeFilter(
    IReadOnlyList<object> arguments, //this from attribute params
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory     //this from DI
)
{
}
```

So ensure your `UserManager` is registered in DI and resolve it in `CustomAuthorizeFilter` constructor.